# Calling a paginated API with promises

Tags: javascript, recursion, typescript, pagination, promise

I want to call a paginated API with promises. The information how many pages are available is not known at the beginning but is delivered on every response. In detail I am calling a Jira [search](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest), the paging information part looks like:

```
{
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 15,
    "total": 100000,
    ...
}
```

I solved the handling of the pagination with recursion, this is my solution in Typescript:

```
search(jql: string, fields: string[] = [], maxResults = 15) : Promise<JiraIssue[]> {
    // container for the issues
    let issues: Array<JiraIssue> = new Array<JiraIssue>();

    // define recursive function to collect the issues per page and
    // perform a recursive call to fetch the next page
    let recursiveFn = (jql: string, fields: string[], startAt: number, maxResults: number) :
        Promise<JiraIssue[]> => {
        return this
            // retrieves one page
            .searchPage(jql, fields, startAt, maxResults)
            .then((searchResult: JiraSearchResult) => {
                // saves the result of the retrieved page
                issues.push.apply(issues, searchResult.issues);
                if (searchResult.startAt + searchResult.maxResults < searchResult.total) {
                    // retrieves the next page with a recursive call
                    return recursiveFn(jql, fields,
                        searchResult.startAt + searchResult.maxResults,
                        maxResults);
                }
                else {
                    // returns the collected issues
                    return issues;
                }
            })

    };

    // and execute it
    return recursiveFn(jql, fields, 0, maxResults);
}
```

However, I don't like the recursive approach, because this works only well with small result sets (I am afraid of a stack overflow). How would you solve this problem with a not recursive approach?

Comment: This is not actual recursion, and there is no stack overflow danger, because the function is being called inside a then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not actual recursion, and there is no stack overflow danger, because the function is being called inside a `then` handler.

Answer (score 1):

One options is to wrap this in an iterator pattern.

Something like:

```
interface Searcher {
    (jql: string, fields: string[], startAt: number, maxResults: number) => Promise<JiraSearchResult>;
}

class ResultsIterator {
    private jql: string;
    private fields: string[];
    private searcher: Searcher;
    private startAt: number;
    private maxResults: number;
    private currentPromise: Promise<JiraIssue[]>;
    private total: number;

    constructor(searcher: Searcher, jql: string, fields?: string[], maxResults?: number) {
        this.jql = jql;
        this.startAt = 0;
        this.searcher = searcher;
        this.fields = fields || [];
        this.maxResults = maxResults || 15;
        this.total = -1;
    }

    hasNext(): boolean {
        return this.total < 0 || this.startAt < this.total;
    }

    next(): Promise<JiraIssue[]> {
        if (!this.hasNext()) {
            throw new Error("iterator depleted");
        }

        return this.searcher(this.jql, this.fields, this.startAt, this.maxResults)
                    .then((searchResult: JiraSearchResult) => {
                        this.total = searchResult.total;
                        this.startAt = searchResult.startAt + searchResult.maxResults;

                        return searchResult.issues;
                    });
    }
}
```

This code isn't perfect, as I'm not entirely sure what you're doing there (for example what's `this.searchPage`?), but you should probably get the idea I'm aiming at.

You'll just do:

```
if (resultIterator.hasNext()) {
    resultIterator.next().then(...);
}
```

Hope this helps.